# How do I choose the minimum value from rows within certain hour range?

Tags: date, excel-formula, min

I have one row per hour for each day. For hours 06:00 to 21:00 I need to use the lowest values ( minimum value) found in Column Price of hours 22:00 (day before) to 05:00 and store it in the column Lowest on each row for hours 06:00 to 21:00. Else column lowes will show the same value as in Price.

How should the Excel formula in column Lowest look like to solve this?

How I need it to look (minimum value shown in Bold)

| Date & hour | DatePart | Hour | Price | Lowest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 00:00 | 2018-01-01 | 00:00 | 258,86 | 258,86 |
| 2018-01-01 01:00 | 2018-01-01 | 01:00 | 259,85 | 259,85 |
| 2018-01-01 02:00 | 2018-01-01 | 02:00 | 256,6 | 256,6 |
| 2018-01-01 03:00 | 2018-01-01 | 03:00 | 242,84 | 242,84 |
| 2018-01-01 04:00 | 2018-01-01 | 04:00 | 243,23 | 243,23 |
| 2018-01-01 05:00 | 2018-01-01 | 05:00 | **177,07** | 177,07 |
| 2018-01-01 06:00 | 2018-01-01 | 06:00 | 174,8 | 177,07 |
| 2018-01-01 07:00 | 2018-01-01 | 07:00 | 175 | 177,07 |
| 2018-01-01 08:00 | 2018-01-01 | 08:00 | 194,27 | 177,07 |
| 2018-01-01 09:00 | 2018-01-01 | 09:00 | 203,81 | 177,07 |
| 2018-01-01 10:00 | 2018-01-01 | 10:00 | 243,43 | 177,07 |
| 2018-01-01 11:00 | 2018-01-01 | 11:00 | 252,47 | 177,07 |
| 2018-01-01 12:00 | 2018-01-01 | 12:00 | 236,84 | 177,07 |
| 2018-01-01 13:00 | 2018-01-01 | 13:00 | 245,89 | 177,07 |
| 2018-01-01 14:00 | 2018-01-01 | 14:00 | 253,75 | 177,07 |
| 2018-01-01 15:00 | 2018-01-01 | 15:00 | 260,14 | 177,07 |
| 2018-01-01 16:00 | 2018-01-01 | 16:00 | 265,75 | 177,07 |
| 2018-01-01 17:00 | 2018-01-01 | 17:00 | 269,68 | 177,07 |
| 2018-01-01 18:00 | 2018-01-01 | 18:00 | 268,3 | 177,07 |
| 2018-01-01 19:00 | 2018-01-01 | 19:00 | 265,06 | 177,07 |
| 2018-01-01 20:00 | 2018-01-01 | 20:00 | 262,5 | 177,07 |
| 2018-01-01 21:00 | 2018-01-01 | 21:00 | 260,24 | 177,07 |
| 2018-01-01 22:00 | 2018-01-01 | 22:00 | 256,5 | 256,5 |
| 2018-01-01 23:00 | 2018-01-01 | 23:00 | 244,61 | 244,61 |
| 2018-01-02 00:00 | 2018-01-02 | 00:00 | 248,54 | 248,54 |
| 2018-01-02 01:00 | 2018-01-02 | 01:00 | **227,7** | 227,7 |
| 2018-01-02 02:00 | 2018-01-02 | 02:00 | 243,62 | 243,62 |
| 2018-01-02 03:00 | 2018-01-02 | 03:00 | 246,08 | 246,08 |
| 2018-01-02 04:00 | 2018-01-02 | 04:00 | 252,96 | 252,96 |
| 2018-01-02 05:00 | 2018-01-02 | 05:00 | 263,88 | 263,88 |
| 2018-01-02 06:00 | 2018-01-02 | 06:00 | 273,32 | 227,7 |
| 2018-01-02 07:00 | 2018-01-02 | 07:00 | 299,86 | 227,7 |
| 2018-01-02 08:00 | 2018-01-02 | 08:00 | 313,92 | 227,7 |
| 2018-01-02 09:00 | 2018-01-02 | 09:00 | 329,65 | 227,7 |
| 2018-01-02 10:00 | 2018-01-02 | 10:00 | 344,5 | 227,7 |
| 2018-01-02 11:00 | 2018-01-02 | 11:00 | 346,27 | 227,7 |
| 2018-01-02 12:00 | 2018-01-02 | 12:00 | 339,78 | 227,7 |
| 2018-01-02 13:00 | 2018-01-02 | 13:00 | 335,25 | 227,7 |
| 2018-01-02 14:00 | 2018-01-02 | 14:00 | 353,74 | 227,7 |
| 2018-01-02 15:00 | 2018-01-02 | 15:00 | 374,09 | 227,7 |
| 2018-01-02 16:00 | 2018-01-02 | 16:00 | 409,68 | 227,7 |
| 2018-01-02 17:00 | 2018-01-02 | 17:00 | 416,76 | 227,7 |
| 2018-01-02 18:00 | 2018-01-02 | 18:00 | 371,53 | 227,7 |
| 2018-01-02 19:00 | 2018-01-02 | 19:00 | 331,32 | 227,7 |
| 2018-01-02 20:00 | 2018-01-02 | 20:00 | 303,6 | 227,7 |
| 2018-01-02 21:00 | 2018-01-02 | 21:00 | 283,64 | 227,7 |
| 2018-01-02 22:00 | 2018-01-02 | 22:00 | 275,18 | 275,18 |
| 2018-01-02 23:00 | 2018-01-02 | 23:00 | 271,35 | 271,35 |

Comment: Do you have office 365? You could use a the `MINIFS` function, putting the criteria for the lower limit as one constraint and the upper as another and have inputs where you can adjust the limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Method** - *volatile and lazy*

You could go with this formula in row 2 of your **Lowest** column *(where Lowest is in column E)* and copied down:

```
=IF(C2=TIME(6,0,0), MIN(OFFSET(D2,-MIN(8,ROW()-1),0,MIN(8,ROW()-1),1)),
   IF( (C2 > TIME(6,0,0))*(C2 < TIME(22,0,0)), E1,
       D2) )
```

I put mine on the side of yours and called it Low to test if the correct answer was reached, where you have your table starting in A1 like this:

[image: result]

In an Excel table (ctrl t) it is more readable like this:

```
=IF([@Hour]=TIME(6,0,0), MIN(OFFSET([@Price],-MIN(8,ROW()-1),0,MIN(8,ROW()-1),1)),
   IF( ([@Hour] > TIME(6,0,0))*([@Hour] < TIME(22,0,0)), E1,
        [@Price]) )
```

**Craner Method** - *non-volatile and non-lazy*

This used INDEX instead of OFFSET as proposed by Scott Craner - should make the worksheet more responsive.

```
=IF(C2=TIME(6,0,0), MIN(INDEX(D:D,MAX(1,ROW()-8)):INDEX(D:D,ROW()-1)),
   IF( (C2 > TIME(6,0,0))*(C2 < TIME(22,0,0)), F1,
        D2) )
```

or in Excel Table:

```
=IF([@Hour]=TIME(6,0,0), MIN(INDEX(D:D,MAX(1,ROW()-8)):INDEX(D:D,ROW()-1)),
   IF( ([@Hour] > TIME(6,0,0))*([@Hour] < TIME(22,0,0)), H1,
        [@Price]) )
```

Comment: NOTE: I posted a wrong answer at first and then deleted and corrected - sorry if you picked up the interim result, but this one is checked.

Comment: True - I thought about an index, but was being lazy.

Comment: Super!  That is really nice.  OK -will edit with an alt soln.

Comment: First, thank you ! The Craner Method works like a charm on a normal worksheet. Second, when I use it in an Excel Table, it will only conclude FALSE , and hence not work. Any clues on why the different logic result?

Comment: Cool! - First, @scott_craner you deserve credit here. To think that you were so close to 128,015 points - I hope you weren't saving up for something. ;-) The only way that I can see it returning a FALSE in **Lowest** is that it picked it up from either  **[@Price]** or  **H1**.  H just happens to be the column that I placed the formula in the Excel Table that I created.  If you copied the formula into your Lowest column and your table starts at A1, then the H1 should be changed E1. But it would be really strange to return a FALSE. Can you check that first?

Comment: Solved! The problem was that Excel didn't update the cell formating to time-format when in Excel Table mode.  Even though I changed the whole column "Hour" to time, it would not refresh and the TIME formula wouldn't work. So, after googling a while I found https://www.groovypost.com/howto/refresh-cell-data-number-formatting-excel/ to force Excel to force-update the culomn formatting to time. Then the IF-statement with the Time-formulas worked! Thanks guys!

Comment: Ahh - that's an interesting situation and not that unusual. Time and Dates are problematic. Same is painfully true everywhere (python, vba, R, etc.). It makes for hard-to-diagnose bugs.  Congrats.

Answer (score 2):

If the data is not sorted use one of these formula.  If the data is sorted like the example shows then the INDEX version of Mark's Formula will be quicker on large datasets.

Nest MINIFS in an IF:

```
=IF(AND(C2>=TIME(6,0,0),C2<=TIME(21,0,0)),MINIFS(D:D,A:A,">="&B2-1+TIME(22,0,0),A:A,"<="&B2+TIME(5,0,0)),D2)
```

[image]

---

If one does not have MINIFS we can use AGGREGATE:

```
=IF(AND(C2>=TIME(6,0,0),C2<=TIME(21,0,0)),AGGREGATE(15,7,$D$2:$D$49/(($A$2:$A$49>=B2-1+TIME(22,0,0))*($A$2:$A$49<=B2+TIME(5,0,0))),1),D2)
```

note that we need to shift from full column references to just the data set.

[image]